# Send data via socket when user hits tab on raw_input in Python

Tags: python, telnet, raw-input

I want to populate a list of commands that are stored over a server when tab is pressed and auto complete can be used only with a local set of words as i read. Is there a way to send ('\t') to the telnet server when user enters tab on raw_input, which would atleast return a list of possible commands along with showing them to user?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then no... You will have to come up with a workaround